# JAVA : Adding to ArrayList causes modification of its content

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to add Arrays of integer to an ArrayList but it seems that each time that a new Array is beeing added, the content of all the others is modified to be the same as the last.

```
for (int a = 0; a<taille; a++) {
    temp[0] = this.caseX-a; 
    temp[1] = this.caseY;
    this.occupe.add(temp);
    for ( int j = 0; j < this.occupe.size(); j++ )
            System.out.println("element " + j + ": " + this.occupe.get(j)[0] );
```

The `caseX` and `caseY` are two integers and my array is `this.occupe`.

The output is :

```
element 0: 4
element 0: 3
element 1: 3
element 0: 2
element 1: 2
element 2: 2
element 0: 1
element 1: 1
element 2: 1
element 3: 1
```

While it should be :

```
element 0: 4
element 0: 4
element 1: 3
element 0: 4
element 1: 3
element 2: 2
element 0: 4
element 1: 3
element 2: 2
element 3: 1
```

Comment: show where the array and ArrayList are declared.

Comment: You always work on the same instance of `temp`, so you are actually overwriting its values on each iteration. You should do `temp = new int[2]` at the beginning of the first `for` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the same object in each adding.
While you need to add distinct objects in the `occupe` `List`.

So instantiate `temp` in each iteration (in the loop and not before).
But in fact you can do simpler. You don't need to introduce an intermediary variable.

You could simply write :

```
this.occupe.add(new int[]{this.caseX-a, this.caseY});
```

The type of element of the `temp` array is not specified.
So change `int[]` if required.